# Proof of application of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Two bicyclists begin a race at 8:00AM. They both finish the race 2 hours and 15 minutes later. Prove/explain that at some point during the race, the bicyclists are traveling at the same velocity.

So far I've tried to make a position graph and a velocity graph to try to explain, but I still can't find a good explanation/"proof".

Comment: *race, not rate.

Comment: The average velocity is given by $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$, the mean value theorem tells you that exists some time $t$ such that the tangent to the time-position graph is parallel to the line that goes through the start and end point, this is, a time such that the velocity $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is exactly the average velocity. Now, both bicyclists started and finished the race at the same time, so both have the same average velocity, what can you conclude?.

Comment: That doesn't mean they have the same velocity at the same time (which is how I took "at some point during the race.") @Cure

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Cure! Since the cyclists position functions are continuous over [8AM,10:15AM] and are differentiable over (8AM,10:15AM), the MVT can be applied to both bicyclists' position functions. The MVT tells us that there is at least 1 one at which the derivative = slope of secant line from a to b. Thus, the cyclists must have each rode at the average velocity at least 1 time from 8AM to 10:15AM. However, they are not necessarily traveling at the same velocity at the same time, as @ThomasAndrews mentioned. Hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea - instead of having position and velocity graphs for the two riders separately, do it for the difference between them. So let $f(t) = f_1(t) - f_2(t)$, where the two numbered functions are the respective positions of the riders. Then what are $f(08:00)$ and $f(10:15)$? And what does $f'(t)$ represent? Can you apply MVT to any of that to get what you need?

Comment: f(08:00) and f(10:15) represent the position difference between the two riders at the respective times. f'(t) would represent rate of change in the difference of position at time t. I don't think this is going anywhere just yet.

Comment: Yes, but where are the runners at those two times, based on the question? And hence, what is the distance between them?

Comment: Incidentally, I'm pretty sure that the solution I'm leading to is correct even if the two runners travel different distances (e.g. one decides to backtrack for a while or take a shortcut or a scenic route).

Comment: I get it now! So f(t) is the difference in position function. Since the function satisfies all requirements for rolles theorem, there must be a time when f'(t)=0. Since f'(t)=v1'(t)-v2'(t), when 0=v1'(t)-v2'(t). So the two speeds are equivalent at some point

Comment: By jove, I think he's got it!

Answer (score 2):

Intuitive explanation: If they never have the same velocity, then one of them must always be going faster than the other. But in that case, can they run the same race in the same amount of time?

Comment: What if one of them takes a longer route? :) I assume, though, that we are expected to believe that they travel the exact same distance...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Quite so. Just as I posted that answer, btw, I had a mental debate about whether I should've said "same race" or "same distance."

Comment: I assumed they run the same distance for the race.